# Show that a matrix has a Cholesky factorization providing that it can be written as a product of a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, orthogonal-matrices

$A$ is an invertible real square matrix ($A \in \mathbb{M_{n}(\mathbb{R})}$ and $det(A) \neq 0$).

Let's consider another matrix $B \in \mathbb{M_{n}(\mathbb{R})}$ such that:
$$B = {}^\intercal A \cdot A$$

Show that $B$ accepts a Cholesky factorization $C \cdot {}^\intercal C$ with $C$ a lower trinagular matrix.

From the first persepctive, I understand that there are exist matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that $D_1 = (D_2)^{-1}$ so $D_1 \cdot D_2 = I_n$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix.

So, we can write $B = {}^{\intercal} A \cdot A = {}^{\intercal} A \cdot I_n \cdot A $
When we replace $I_n$ with $D_1 \cdot D_2$, we will have:

$$B = {}^\intercal A \cdot D_1 \cdot D_2 \cdot A$$
We choose the matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ in a way that: $C = {}^\intercal A \cdot D_1$ and ${}^\intercal C = D_2 \cdot A$

I guess that the Gauss elimination matrices should be involved in some way to turn  ${}^\intercal A \cdot A$ to the form $C \cdot {}^\intercal C$, but I do not know how they should be related to the matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ and how to formalize the proof as well.

Comment: I have added a link to an answer that contains the key ingredient that you need to answer you problem. If it does not work for you, then a few words of explanation.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Your are welcome. When you find any answer useful, then you should upvote it.

Comment: I am still a member with 11 reputation, thus no ability to upvote or downvote. It would be nice if you upvote my question so that I can reach 15 and upvote your answer : ).

Comment: My mistake, I had forgotten about the 15 point barrier.

Comment: I have arrived to find another answer for the question posted.

Comment: I have arrived to find another answer to the question posted. To prove the above, we need to demonstrate in some way that the matrices is a positive defined matrix. So, for that, we need to review the definition of a positive defined matrix, in other words: let X be a vector in R^n different from the null vector. B is positived defined matrix means that: transpose(X)*B*X > 0. The previous formula will become: tr(X)*(tr(A)*A)*X = tr(A*X)*(A*X) which is the square of the second norm of the marix A ||A||_2 (always positive). B is positive defined so it has a Cholesky decomposition.